# How check a external tension with an ESP8266

Tags: esp8266

I have a small project with an ESP8266, on which on a PIO I need to retrieve the presence or absence of an external voltage, from another totally independent circuit. The voltage I need to check is under 24V.  I need an isolation between both circuits. What's the best way to find out whether or not this voltage is present, and bring this information to the ESP8266?

Comment: Any reason you can't use a GPIO pin and a voltage divider?

Comment: Do you need electrical isolation between both circuits?

Comment: Yes I need an isolation between both circuits

Comment: Edit your question to include that and any other requirements.

Comment: I've found a [similar question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/455436/opto-isolator-to-read-30v-with-esp8266-3v3-input). I will use an opto-isolator / optocoupler.

Comment: If you need only determine presence of isolated voltage, optocoupler can be used.

Comment: The word is voltage in english, never tension.

Answer (score 1):

A simple voltage divider made of 2 resistors would be the easiest option
https://ohmslawcalculator.com/voltage-divider-calculator
R1=100k R2=15k you would get ~3.2V out and a current leak of 0.2mA depending on your system such a setup would work but doesnt provide protection for over voltage (maybe a diode would help? also a serie resistor to the mcu adc pin?)

Comment: Nicolas de Grave - Hi, Thanks for trying to help. Unfortunately, after you posted this answer, the OP clarified in their question that they need isolation between the measured voltage & the MCU, so a simple voltage divider is not an appropriate solution for them. The question then became a duplicate of an existing question and [the OP later mentioned that as a solution](/posts/comments/1788206). || You didn't break any rules, but as you are new here, please see the [tour] & [help] to see the main site rules, as they differ from ones on typical forums. Thanks.